# Python Tkinter.py is incorrect

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Hey I am trying to create a small quiz and this error code keeps popping up. `

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Untitled-1.py", line 13, in <module>
    text.config(root, height=50, width=50, state="disabled")
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1262, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1253, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-colormap"
Kestas-iMac:Python scripts jonahfleming$ python Untitled-1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Untitled-1.py", line 13, in <module>
    text.config(root, height=50, width=50, state="disabled")
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1262, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1253, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-colormap"
```

I have tried to fix the problem but couldn't edit it.

Comment: You need to post you code, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you reconfigure a Tkinter widget, you don't need to send it the root object.

```
text.config(height=50, width=50, state="disabled")
```

Also, when you see an exception in a library or framework that you're using, it's almost always because you're using it incorrectly, not because the framework itself is buggy (or "incorrect").